# Fetch big binary data from CouchDB using c#

Tags: c#, couchdb

I use CouchDB as Content server to store images and large video files
the problem is when i retrieve these files it represented as document response and it needs to deserialize to get the binary files and that will cause **out of memory error** (for any file larger than 300mb).

Here is the Upload function

```
  public async Task<string> InsertDataToCouchDb(string dbName, string id, string recodNo, string filename, byte[] image)
    {
        var connection = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CouchDb"].ConnectionString;
        using (var db = new MyCouchClient(connection, dbName))
        {

            // HERE I NEED TO UPLOAD MY IMAGE BYTE[] AS CHUNKS 
            var artist = new couchdb
            {
                _id = id,
                filename = filename,
                Image = image
            };

            var response = await db.Entities.PutAsync(artist);
            return  response.Content._id;
        }

    }
```

The Download Function

```
   public async Task<byte[]> FetchDataFromCouchDb(string dbName, string id)
    {
        var connection = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CouchDb"].ConnectionString;
        using (var db = new MyCouchClient(connection, dbName))
        {
            //HERE I NEED TO RETRIVE MY FULL IMAGE[] FROM CHUNKS
            var test = await db.Documents.GetAsync(id, null);

            var doc = db.Serializer.Deserialize<couchdb>(test.Content);
            return doc.Image;

        }
    }
```

I need to get the binary data directly without any deserialization like mongoDB GridFSBucket

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing it the wrong way, the attachment must be separated from the document by using the Attachment object.

```
var response = await db.Entities.PutAsync(artist);//The document
                var request = new PutAttachmentRequest(
                    id,
                    response.Rev,//from the added document
                    "filename",
                    HttpContentTypes.Text,
                    filebytes);

                var xxx = await db.Attachments.PutAsync(request);
```

//Here how you can read the file
                    AttachmentResponse resAtt = await db.Attachments.GetAsync(id, "filename");

```
                var filebytes2 = resAtt.Content;//no deserialize
```

Comment: must pass filename here , took  5 hour to find it.  var test = await db.Attachments.GetAsync(id, fileName);